# aws ecs perfomance doesn't increase on single instance

Tags: docker, containers, amazon-ecs

I'm coming across an issue where if I add a second container from the same image serving a website to a cluster with a single ECS instance the performance using loaderio doesn't increase but when I add a second ECS instance to the cluster then add the second container to that instance performance increases dramatically.

CPU and Memory are not close to their limits but I do feel like this could be a networking issue as I'm using docker bridge network mode. Or possibly the ALB sending sending all traffic to one ECS instance is too much.

Any idea?

Comment: What is the underlying EC2 instance type you are using?

Comment: We're using m4.large.